# Stream Spotify preview_url in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, mp3, spotify

I am trying to stream the preview url Spotify provides from their [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) which is working well and I am getting correct links but they are not playing properly.

A sample url would be https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/757bc5732e5c92e36ea249d631120b381a4885e2?cid=e188f3e083e741659b2ef6cfb07cddbd.mp3 and I am attempting to the exact same code that is discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555049/how-to-stream-audio-from-url-without-downloading-mp3-file-on-device/53568482), and I can get it to work with the URL they provide in the question but it doesn't work with the Spotify samples. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
       let url = URL(string: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/757bc5732e5c92e36ea249d631120b381a4885e2?cid=e188f3e083e741659b2ef6cfb07cddbd.mp3")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
    playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:50)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

The spotify preview url of of type only for 30 seconds. They can be played via AVPlayer,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class AudioVC : UIViewController {
var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let previewURL = "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/757bc5732e5c92e36ea249d631120b381a4885e2?cid=e188f3e083e741659b2ef6cfb07cddbd.mp3"

         downloadFileFromURL(url: URL(string: previewURL)!)

       }

    func downloadFileFromURL(url: URL){
        var downloadTask = URLSessionDownloadTask()
        downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            customURL, response, error in

            self.play(url: customURL!)

        })

        downloadTask.resume()


    }

    func play(url: URL) {

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()

        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }}
 }
```